# Pandas/python analyse frequency histogram by a column and aggregate another column to those buckets

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, histogram, frequency

I am using pandas with a dataframe like below:

| Name | percent | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 34 |
| B | 5 | 200 |
| C | 30 | 20 |
| D | 1 | 12 |

I want to create buckets for the `percent` column such as `0-5`, `6-15`, `>16`. With these buckets I record both the count of `percent` column (which is effectively a histogram) but also record the **average** of `Amount` in that same bucket.

Using the above example:

| Bucket | percent count | Avg. Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 3 | 82 |
| 15 | 0 | 0 |
| >15 | 1 | 20 |

How can I achieve this in `python` and `pandas` (or any other library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) and [`groupby`+`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
(df.assign(Bucket=pd.cut(df['percent '],
                         [0, 5, 15, float('inf')],
                         labels=['0-5', '6-15', '>15']))
   .groupby('Bucket').agg(**{'percent count': ('percent ', 'count'),
                            'Avg. Amount': ('Amount', 'mean')
                           })
   .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
  Bucket  percent count  Avg. Amount
0    0-5              3           82
1   6-15              0            0
2    >15              1           20
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), [`Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) and [`Groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
In [232]: import numpy as np

In [233]: conds = [df['percent'].between(0,5), df['percent'].between(6,15), df['percent'].gt(15)]

In [234]: choices = ['5', '15', '>15']

In [237]: df['Bucket'] = np.select(conds, choices)

In [245]: res = df.groupby('Bucket').agg({'percent': 'count', 'Amount': 'mean'}).reindex(choices).fillna(0).astype(int).reset_index()

In [246]: res
Out[246]: 
  Bucket  percent  Amount
0      5        3      82
1     15        0       0
2    >15        1      20
```

**Timings:**

@mozway's solution:

```
In [257]: def f2():
     ...:     (df.assign(Bucket=pd.cut(df['percent'],[0, 5, 15, float('inf')],labels=['0-5', '6-15', '>15'])).groupby('Bucket').agg(**{'percent count': ('percent', 'count'),'Avg. Amount': ('Amount', 'mean')}).fillna(0, dow
     ...: ncast='infer').reset_index())
     ...: 

In [258]: %timeit f2()
8.02 ms ± 587 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

My solution:

```
In [253]: def f1():
     ...:     conds = [df['percent'].between(0,5), df['percent'].between(6,15), df['percent'].gt(15)]
     ...:     choices = ['5', '15', '>15']
     ...:     df['Bucket'] = np.select(conds, choices)
     ...:     res = df.groupby('Bucket').agg({'percent': 'count', 'Amount': 'mean'}).reindex(choices).fillna(0).astype(int).reset_index()
     ...: 

In [254]: %timeit f1()
3.64 ms ± 371 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: @bcsta Please check my answer as well. It's much faster than mozway's answer.